# Wildcard pattern does not match literal dot?

Tags: msbuild

In a targets file, I have the following item group:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MyGroup Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\dist\**\*.*">
  </MyGroup>
</ItemGroup>
```

I want to match all files which have an extension (contain a dot in their name), but the pattern above is matching files that have no extension (e.g., README). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it in two steps :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Tmp Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\dist\**\*.*">
  </Tmp>
  <MyGroup Include="@(Tmp)" Condition="'%(Tmp.Extension)' != ''" >
  </MyGroup>
</ItemGroup>

<Message Text="@(MyGroup)" />
<Message Text="@(Tmp)" />
```

Comment: Is it the case that there is no practical difference between `*.*` and `*` wildcard patterns?

Comment: The MSBuild source for [FileMatcher](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/1510d9a8cf346f01919c5b9545ef0b1a25bfbe9d/src/Shared/FileMatcher.cs#L882) confirms that `*.*` and `*` are equivalent, which is very surprising to me.